# VS2013 MFC Symbols missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mfc, debug-symbols, symbol-server

My Visual Studio 2013 is unable to load MFC symbols.
After setting some options in Visual Studio, I am able to load symbols for most of the Windows DLLs, but MFC symbols (more exact: `mfc120ud.i386.pdb` and `mfc120d.i386.pdb`) are still missing.

What I have tried so far:

- Enabled the Microsoft Symbol Servers.
- Under "Automatically load symbols for:" selected "All modules, unless excluded"
- Unchecked "Just My Code"
- Searched locally for the files

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default setting of Microsoft Symbol Servers only uses HTTP protocol, but loading MFC symbols seems to require HTTPS.

When `https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` is added to the symbol file locations, the missing MFC symbols were loaded successfully.